# Alternative characterisation of supremum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction, supremum-and-infimum, recursion

Given a sequence $\{b_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, can we define $\alpha_k=\sup_{j\geq k} b_j$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ recursively through $\alpha_j=\max\{b_j,\alpha_{j+1}\}$ for all $j\geq k$? I am able to show that $\alpha_k\geq \sup_{j\geq k} b_j$, but due to the backward structure of the definition I am unable to show the other direction, as my attempt by contradiction failed. Could it be that my intuition about the equivalence of this characterisation of the supremum is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This characterisation is necessary but not sufficient for $\alpha_k=\sup_{j\geq k}b_j$. Consider $\{b_j\}=(0,0,0,...)$ and $\{\alpha_j\}=(1,1,1,...)$, then $\alpha_j=\max\{b_j,\alpha_{j+1}\}$ but $\alpha_k>\sup_{j\geq k}b_j$.

Comment: could there be additional conditions to make it sufficient too?

Comment: Maybe we could truncate the recursion at some point to make it finite, then send the truncation point to infinity. For example, let $\{\beta_j^{(n)}\}$ be such that $\beta_j^{(n)}=\max\{b_j,\beta_{j+1}^{(n)}\}$ if $j<n$ and $\beta_j^{(n)}=b_n$ if $j\geq n$, then let $\alpha_j=\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_j^{(n)}$.

Comment: You could say let $\alpha_j$ be the minimum sequence satisfying the condition $\alpha_j=\max\{b_j,\alpha_{j+1}\}$, under the relation of element-wise comparison, i.e., if $\alpha_j'$ is any other sequence satisfying that condition, then $\alpha_j\leq\alpha_j'$ for all $j$.  Of course, this starts to feel similar to the usual characterization of supremum.